# No data with QProcess.waitForReadyRead(): non consistent behavior

Tags: python, pyqt4

I experienced this bug in a more complex application I am developing. I execute a python server program and want to read the first data available. And then close it. I do that to validate some settings from the server.

My problem boils down to:

- QProcess.waitForReadyRead() doesn't return and timeouts, it's supposed to return True very quickly
- It used to work, I rollbacked to an older revision to try to find what caused this to break now, but it's always there now, I really tried everything I could think of, so I want to know if it's a normal problem or maybe something that would only affect me and caused by my environment.

This is the test I wrote to show the problem, when I execute it, the 3 first checks return the data immediately, but the last one timeouts and I get no data.

This is certainly not logical. In the test I used wait, in my server it's just a select-like function, it's implemented with base modules in python.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

#FILE: 1.py
#print 'TEST'

#FILE: 2.py
# import time
#print 'TEST'
#time.sleep(100)

#FILE: 1.sh
# echo 'TEST'

#FILE: 2.sh
# echo 'TEST'
# sleep 100


proc0= QtCore.QProcess()
proc0.start('sh', ['./1.sh'])
proc0.waitForStarted()
proc0.waitForReadyRead(10000)
output0 = proc0.readAll()

proc1= QtCore.QProcess()
proc1.start('sh', ['./2.sh'])
proc1.waitForStarted()
proc1.waitForReadyRead(10000)
output1 = proc1.readAll()

proc2= QtCore.QProcess()
proc2.start('python', ['./1.py'])
proc2.waitForStarted()
proc2.waitForReadyRead(10000)
output2 = proc2.readAll()

proc3= QtCore.QProcess()
proc3.start('python', ['./2.py'])
proc3.waitForStarted()
proc3.waitForReadyRead(10000)
output3 = proc3.readAll()

print "0"
print output0.size()
print repr(output0.data())
print "1"
print output1.size()
print repr(output1.data())
print "2"
print output2.size()
print repr(output2.data())
print "3"
print output3.size()
print repr(output3.data())

proc0.close()
proc1.close()
proc2.close()
proc3.close()
```

Is the last test (proc3) supposed to behave like I described? Is there a workaround or a fix that would let me read the data form stdout in my python server...? What is it?

Comment: I found the solution, python's print doesn't flush stdout and waits for a certain amount of data before actually pushing the data to the stdout. sys.stdout.flush() fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a comment but...

I found the solution, python's print doesn't flush stdout and waits for a certain amount of data before actually pushing the data to the stdout. sys.stdout.flush() fixed it.

Hope it helps.